# In PyCharm how do I remove the outputs of my Jupyter Notebook when running from the IDE?

Tags: pycharm, jupyter-notebook

If I run a piece of python code in from a cell in my IPython NoteBook, the output is displayed in my IDE below the selected cell. I want to remove this output (and/or any output from other cells) from the view. When I access the notebook through the Jupyter URL, I can reset the kernel and clear all results.

How can I reset/clear the output in my IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this feature is still missing in PyCharm, as confirmed by one of the JetBrains employees [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000094190-PyCharm-support-for-Jupyter-Notebooks-is-simply-terrible?page=1#community_comment_360000085104).

So I guess you have to do it directly by accessing the Jupyter URL (e.g., in the browser) or open the file as JSON and manually delete the output.

Comment: I tried using notebooks within PyCharm but quickly moved out of it. There's just too little one could do with them.
It would be so much better if they improved the features within the IDE so we could just manage everything in one place.

Comment: Anyone here has an idea if this feature is planned?

Comment: Check this out - https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/whatsnew/?utm_source=marketo&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=pycharm&utm_content=newsletter&mkt_tok=eyJpIjoiWXpkbE16STBPVGt3WkRVMSIsInQiOiJ3MG82RXRYenhKQ29jXC9ubzhmS0MwQjVJWGE2bVZHSk9XM1d5XC8rb3doeXNKNjZcL3Y0OThpMU5xNDB4YzhSQTd5alEyMFlxZEQ1MmNqdjlDakVPbXZnSkEra2lQWXdmVTNSMEt0TnBiTVNmbHc0U2xpdEg4UFNXWnRIZE56N2JyKyJ9#v2019-1-edit-jupyter 
I still haven't explored it; so cannot confirm whether this feature is included but seems like a lot of new features related to Jupyter Notebooks have been added.

Answer (score 25):

For PyCharm 2021.3 the bulb icon ([previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64566084/14483179)) is no longer there. Just tap *shift* twice and look for "Clear Outputs".

Comment: Thank you so much for this.  Using my newfound knowledge of "Clear Outputs", I was able to add a button to my main toolbar, and my life is so much more complete as a result.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm able to add a shortcut to 'Restart  Kernel and Clear Outputs' I couldn't find the right place in 'Settings... > Apprance & Behavior > Menus and Toolbars' to add the action such that a button shows up on the Jupyter editor. Any idea?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't seem to be there. I added it to: Navigation Bar toolbar/Toolbar Run Actions, right after the stop button. It is shown always but at least it is disabled when you are not in a Jupyter notebook.

Comment: For 2023.1, it's here  -> https://imgur.com/a/3elY8V3

Answer (score 13):

This feature is already in pycharm.
In the top of the window there is a lamp which contains the main features of jupyter notbook including clean the outputs.

Comment: by lamp do you mean light bulb?

Comment: This answer should be the accepted answer. Please change the accepted answer to this one. @Timo

Answer (score 2):

The new Data Science focused IDE from Pycharm called DataSpell has the feature. At the right end of your output cell, there are 3 dots. Simply click on them and clear the output.

Answer (score 1):

The feature is planned for 2019.2 - you can vote for it here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-34789